# calculateAge (or year) from LINQ Query DateTime field using C# for comparision (Age From)

Tags: c#, linq

please see calculateAge to convert the Birthdate to current age in years in LINQ Query (it works for other keys, ex: EyeColor, but age conversion failing), I would like to compare with the value that was stored in Array. I tried storing the value in DateTime temp variable above the link, right below "case "AgeTo":" but I can not take the value x.profile.BirthDate as it's allowed only within LINQ Query. It appears that LINQ query is not giving error during build, however, it's failing to con

Error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   calculateAge(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

Any help how to handle?

Code and calculateAge method:

```
if (searchList.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> kvp in searchList)
    {
        switch (kvp.Key)
        {
            case "AgeFrom":
                photosquery = photosquery.Where(x => calculateAge(Convert.ToDateTime(x.profile.BirthDate)) >= Convert.ToInt32(kvp.Value));
                break;
            case "AgeTo":
                photosquery = photosquery.Where(x => calculateAge(Convert.ToDateTime(x.profile.BirthDate)) <= Convert.ToInt32(kvp.Value));
                break;
            case "EyeColor":
                photosquery = photosquery.Where(x => x.physical.EyesColor.Contains(kvp.Value));
                break;
        }
    }
}

//My code for calculateAge:

public static int calculateAge(DateTime birthDay)
{
    int years = DateTime.Now.Year - birthDay.Year;

    if ((birthDay.Month > DateTime.Now.Month) || (birthDay.Month == DateTime.Now.Month && birthDay.Day > DateTime.Now.Day))
        years--;

    return years;
}
```

Comment: You do realise that if you perform your code near midnight if might fail? Better ask only once for the current time, to ensure that all items in your search list are compared using the same time. Also easier to write a decent specification: "This function calculates the age of all items in the collection at the moment the function is called". The result will be predictable, regardless of how fast your procedure performs. Furthermore consider using DateTime.Today, instead of DateTime.Now

Comment: Good point, I’ll change the code as get back to you on my success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an easier solution.  Rather than comparing the age, compare the dates themselves.

```
case "AgeFrom":
    var fromAge = Convert.ToInt32(kvp.Value);
    var maxDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-fromAge);
    photosquery = photosquery.Where(x => x.profile.BirthDate <= maxDate);
    break;
case "AgeTo":
    var toAge = Convert.ToInt32(kvp.Value);
    var minDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-toAge-1).AddDays(1);
    photosquery = photosquery.Where(x => x.profile.BirthDate >= minDate);
    break;
```

This has the added benefit of making the query [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable), so it can make use of an index, assuming you've created one on the `BirthDate` field.

Comment: THank you for the help Matt JOhnson, this worked for me. BirthDate field is DateTime field and it can be compared with converted maxDate or minDate variables.. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Can someone respond to the below (similar) question? This time I ned to compare with numeric value.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46855132/convert-to-int-from-string-from-linq-query-field-using-c-sharp-for-comparison-h

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're getting this error is that your `Where`-clause is being invoked on your Entity queryable, and it doesn't know how to translate the C# code into the equivalent for your database language.

If you were able to rewrite the internals of that function into something that didn't have .NET-based variable storage or referenced only CLR functions that are available in the database you could use it inline, as if you didn't have the function call:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
...    
case "AgeFrom":
    photosquery = photosquery.Where(x => DbFunctions.DiffYears(x.profile.BirthDate,now) >= Convert.ToInt32(kvp.Value));
    break;
```

If you want to use the code you have though, you'll need to retrieve all of the data before filtering, which is not generally recommended. You could still achieve this by calling .ToList() before your .Where(..) clause.

Comment: Thanks Rob, looks like I missed your comment. I’ll try it.

Comment: Rob, I got it worked with Matt's response, thanks for the help. DbFunctions class is fairly usable as well. I'll keep a note for future calculations.

Comment: Hi, can someone review the SQL syntax and help me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849473/select-statement-has-case-that-provies-select-value-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You are working with `IQueryable`, so you can't mix it with arbitrary `C#` code before materialization.

Now you have two options:

1. Load all your data into app memory with `ToList` or `ToArray` and apply your filtering method
2. Rewrite your query to use some `sql` functions (`DATEPART` for this case)

For second way you can write this query (before `switch`):

```
var newQuery = photosquery.Select(x => new
{
    AllQuery = x,
    yearsDiff = (x.profile.BirthDate.Month > now.Month) ||
                (x.profile.BirthDate.Month == now.Month 
                   && x.profile.BirthDate.Day > now.Day)
        ? now.Year - x.profile.BirthDate.Year - 1
        : now.Year - x.profile.BirthDate.Year
});
```

Then when you enter your `switch` you can write:

```
case "AgeFrom":
  photosquery = newQuery
      .Where(x => x.yearsDiff >= Convert.ToInt32(kvp.Value))
      .Select(x => x.AllQuery );
  break;
```