# Convert to Int from String from LINQ Query field using C# for comparison (Height From)

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to use the linq query, when I try to convert the height value somehow I'm getting error during runtime.

Error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

Is there a better way to compare the height value?

```
case "HeightFrom":
     photosquery = photosquery.Where(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.physical.BodyHeight.TrimEnd()) >= Convert.ToInt32(height));
     break;
```

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but can you guarentee that `BodyHeight` and `Height`  will _always_ be convertable into `int`?  You are running a pretty high risk of an exception, why not create `int` properties on your model that have the proper error handling `int.TryParse()` and then just compare the new `int` properties?

Comment: Avoid doing manipulations of any kind on the database field (the left-side).  That will always result in a nonsargable query.

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't seem to be well supported in Linq-to-Entities, see this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16694769/4276832

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the Linq provider (probably from EF) you are using doesn't support `Convert.ToInt32`. A quick solution to this issue is using `AsEnumerable` extension method to switch to Linq to Objects

```
 photosquery = photosquery.AsEnumerale()
                          .Where(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.physical.BodyHeight.TrimEnd()) >= Convert.ToInt32(height));
```

Now if `BodyHeight` is a string and you are saving an integer, I strongly suggest to change the type of that column if you can. Your query could be executed entirely in the server side:

```
int value=Convert.ToInt32(height);
photosquery = photosquery.Where(x => x.physical.BodyHeight >= value);
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion. Let me see if I can change the table design to integer instead of string. I know it's going to be tedious task in changing the data for less than 1000 records, but this should resolve the problem permanently. I have numieric value for display (ex: dropdownlist text provide height - 6' 2", but I may have value as 62, based on user search, I need to compare the value and bring the matched data using linq. That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I think doing that change you will have a permanent solution and a better performance in your queries. Try to validate the user input and do the cast before create  the query

Comment: I converted to int for the column, luckily existing data was accepted as is. Now, I'm removing the table from edmx and adding it back with the design change. I may have to modify the code in few aspx.cs files and that should work. It's easier than making a change to the code. Thaks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
case "HeightFrom":
 var h = Convert.ToInt32(height);
 photosquery = photosquery.Where(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.physical.BodyHeight.TrimEnd()) >= h);
 break;
```

EF won't know how to translate that last convert. If the first one doesn't work, just try `int.parse(x.physical.BodyHeight.TrimEnd())` or a direct cast `(int)x.physical.BodyHeight.TrimEnd()`

If it were me, and I had the time, I would probably map that model to another model with the correct data types before I started querying.

Comment: As you have correclty pointed out that EF won't know how to translate that last convert, the same holds for the first convert :)

Comment: THe problem is with physical.BodyHeight value conversion to int, not the height value. I get the same error as below:

{"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not a lot you can use

```
case "HeightFrom": photosquery = photosquery.ToList().Where(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.physical.BodyHeight.TrimEnd()) >= Convert.ToInt32(height)); break;
```

But for heavy data is not ok and load all data at first then filter it

Comment: I would like to filter at the end - using TOList().