# Select Statement has Case that provies select value - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select, case

I want to select UserType, UserID, FirstName, LastName, UserName from Users table. if PhotoURL is available from Photos table, I select. If record does not exists (UserType - admin only has record in Photos table), I should send spaces.

The query is below. If you think of better query, please suggest.

```
Select UserType, UserID, FirstName, LastName, UserName,
CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT PhotoURL FROM Photos WHERE Photos.UserID = Users.UserID AND UserType = 'admin' AND Photos.PhotoNum = 1
    )
    THEN (
        SELECT PhotoURL FROM Photos WHERE Photos.UserID = Users.UserID AND UserType = 'admin' AND Photos.PhotoNum = 1
    ) 
    ELSE '' 
END AS PhotoURL
from Users
```

Comment: Is the query you tried not working? If not, what is the error?

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: That error means you have more than one `PhotoNum` 1 for the same `UserID`. Although you can return those multiple rows for the same user using the suggested `LEFT JOIN` technique, you might have a data issue since I would expect there should be a primary key or unique constraint  on `UserID` and `PhotoNum` of the `Photos` table.

Comment: The error was because of not checking uysertype as Admin. Good point.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT UserType, Users.UserID, FirstName, LastName, UserName, ISNULL(Photos.PhotoURL, '') as PhotoURL
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Photos on Users.UserID = Photos.UserID 
    AND Photos.PhotoNum = 1
    AND Users.UserType = 'admin'
```

Comment: The where clauses forces to execute query like inner join. You should consider the no matching.

Comment: That’s what the isnull at the last column is doing

Comment: "AND Photos.PhotoNum = 1" this condition eliminates the possible null records of Photos.

Comment: Thank you so much, this query worked like a champ. I appreciate it.

Comment: Can someone provide a suggestion for another issue with asp:Image issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861477/aspx-image-on-error-if-image-not-availble-in-path-avoid-showing-error-image

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a `left join`

```
    Select UserType, UserID, FirstName, LastName, UserName, ISNULL(P.PhotoURL,'')
    from Users U left join Photos P
    ON U.UserID = P.UserID
    where 
    U.UserType = 'admin' and
    (P.PhotoNum is null OR P.PhotoNum = 1) -- No match in the photos table or if there is a match, PhotoNum should be 1
```

Comment: Good suggestion. Thank you for the quick response.